# Using fg with screen

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, gnu-screen

I have a running job in a ssh terminal on an external server. I can pause it with `CTRL + Z` and resume it with `fg`. But I would like to pause it, run screen `screen -S my_job` and get it back in front with `fg`. It does not work.
Is there a way to do something like this?

The reason is that my job is running quite a long time (1 month) and will run for two more months. If my desktop computer dies because of a blackout, my job will be killed.

Comment: Start your job inside `screen`. Then even if the connection fails you can reconnect to `screen`.

Comment: I know, but I forgot to do that a month ago. It is running at the moment.

Comment: Use `retty` or `reptyr`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is the controlling terminal of the job. I'm not aware of any method to change the controlling terminal, which you'd need to do if you wanted to move your program into a screen.

However, if your job has no important input or output on its standard input/output/error, you might consider the shell builtin `disown`, which removes a background job from the table of active jobs. This implies that the shell will *not* send the job a SIGHUP when it dies (e.g. due to connection failure of your ssh'ing host). Example:

```
$ long-running-job
^Z
$ bg
(shell displays backgrounding notification)
$ disown
```

And your job should run on. It's I/O will be closed, though, so that's no help if you have any stdin/stdout/stderr activity.

Comment: This is a good solution, thank you. But I think I am going to use `reptyr`. So I get the output of my job.